# Laravel Carbon how to change timezone without changing the hour

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5

I am trying to find a workaround for how I can convert the datetime stored in my Database as 'yyyy-mm-dd HH-mm-ss' and give it the timezone 'America/Los_Angeles'.

If I change the timezone, Carbon will automatically subtract 7 hours from the time, which is what happens when changing the time from UTC to PST, but the time in my DB is set for PST time. For example, I want the time to be 10am today, but it I change the timezone, Carbon will convert it to 3am today.

How can I make it where the timezone gets changed to PST but still keep the time at 10am? I need the timezone for an API call, which is why I need this figured out.

Comment: What a mess.  This is why all servers and dates should always be configured/stored as UTC.

Comment: My server is set to UTC, but I stored the dates as PST, as I have never needed to use the timezone before.

Comment: If your date-time strings do not themselves contain a timezone, you should be able to simply change the `'timezone' => 'UTC'` declaration in your `config/app.php`. This will instruct Carbon / DateTime to interpret any datetime strings in that specific timezone by default, so you won't have to convert the timezone every time on all Carbon instances (which WILL change the date and/or time).

Comment: UTC all the times!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a dumb, but functional way of doing what I wanted to do, and it works.

Here is my code:

```
      $dt = Carbon::parse($request->ShootDateTime)->timezone('America/Los_Angeles');
      $toDay = $dt->format('d');
      $toMonth = $dt->format('m');
      $toYear = $dt->format('Y');
      $dateUTC = Carbon::createFromDate($toYear, $toMonth, $toDay, 'UTC');
      $datePST = Carbon::createFromDate($toYear, $toMonth, $toDay, 'America/Los_Angeles');
      $difference = $dateUTC->diffInHours($datePST);
      $date = $dt->addHours($difference);
```

I get the time I wanted to convert to a timezone and parse it and change the timezone. I then get the Day, Month, and Year and create 2 different Dates, both will read as being 00:00:00 in time, but because they are separate by 7 hours in this instance, they can only both be 00:00:00 if they are 7 hours different, which is what I capture next. Then finally, I take the initial datetime and add the difference to it, giving me the proper time in the proper timezone.

It's ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 71):

Use the `shiftTimezone()` method instead of `setTimezone()`.

If you call `setTimezone()` on an existing instance of Carbon,
it will change the date/time to the new timezone, for example:

```php
$datetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-09-15 23:45:00');
echo $datetime->toAtomString() . "\n";
// 2020-09-15T23:45:00+00:00

$datetime->setTimezone('America/Los_Angeles');
echo $datetime . "\n";
// 2020-09-15T16:45:00-07:00
```

However, calling `shiftTimezone()` instead will set the
timezone without changing the time. Lets try it again from the start:

```php
$datetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-09-15 23:45:00');
echo $datetime->toAtomString() . "\n";
// 2020-09-15T23:45:00+00:00

$datetime->shiftTimezone('America/Los_Angeles');
echo $datetime->toAtomString() . "\n";
// 2020-09-15T23:45:00-07:00
```

Of course you can chain the methods together as well:

```php
$datetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-09-15 23:45:00')
    ->shiftTimezone('America/Los_Angeles');
echo $datetime->toAtomString() . "\n";
// 2020-09-15T23:45:00-07:00
```

You can also "shift" the timezone by passing the timezone as part of the
`settings` array:

```php
$datetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-09-15 23:45:00')
    ->settings(['timezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles']);
echo $datetime->toAtomString() . "\n";
// 2020-09-15T23:45:00-07:00
```

Comment: Thanks, Donatello. Should be the right answer.

Answer (score 27):

I think that what you'r looking for is this:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $some_date, 'UTC')
    ->setTimezone('America/Los_Angeles')
```

First, you set the timezone you initially have, so if you store your date in the database as UTC, then set the default timezone to UTC, then use `->setTimeZone('Valid/Timezone')` to make the change from what you'v had to the new timezone.

Answer (score 10):

A better and simpler way would be:

```
$carbon = new Carbon('YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS', 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

NOTE: Don't forget to add dependency `use \Carbon\Carbon;`.

Answer (score 8):

My response to this question will be a little different. For my situation, I had a date string that needed to be parsed as if it was the 0th hour (midnight) on the given day **in a custom timezone** - but all the dates in my database are **tracked in UTC**, so what I really needed to do was keep the date in UTC timezone, but give it kind a "reverse offset" of what the expected timezone was.

Situation: I get a datestring of "2020-09-02" that I will use to see if X records have a field that is on or after this same date; however, I am in the America/Chicago timezone which currently is -05:00 from UTC, so I need to adjust the UTC version of this date string to be 2020-09-02 05:00 to accurately account for midnight in my timezone.

To do that, I needed to parse the datestring as being in the America/Chicago timezone, and then change the timezone to UTC:

```php
$value = "2020-09-02"
Carbon::parse($value . '  America/Chicago')->tz('UTC')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Return the formated date based on timezone selected from sidebar nav | Front-end user | Saved in Cookie | Sent $to
 *
 * @param Carbon $date
 * @param null $type (long | short)
 * @return Carbon date
 */
public static function formatDateTimeZone($date, $type = 'long', $from = null, $to = null)
{
    if (!$from)
        $from = 'UTC';

    if (!$to)
        $to = Cookie::get('timezone_user');

    $dateUTC = Carbon::now();
    $datePST = Carbon::now();
    $datePST->setTimezone($to);

    $start  = new Carbon($dateUTC);
    $end    = new Carbon($datePST);
    $difference = $start->diffInHours($end, false); // set false to see the negative difference

    $carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date, $from); // specify UTC otherwise defaults to locale time zone as per ini setting
    $carbon->addHours($difference);

    if ($type == 'short')
    {
        $carbon = Carbon::parse($carbon)->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    return $carbon;
}
```

call: `$date = Date::formatDateTimeZone(Carbon::parse('2019-11-01 06:00:00'), 'long', 'UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles');`

I've created this function to format the dates saved in Database as UTC and show it correctly to chart.

It makes the difference of actual timezone hours and applies the same logic for old dates. (e.g. 2019-11-04 where the difference is -7h)

Laravel **5.8**

Answer (score 0):

`Carbon::parse` second param is a timezone setter for the string you want to parse, this gives you the ability to parse your date string to your desired timezone and keeps the hour/seconds intact.

Here's the [link](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/f43ff0e4b5f658dc2dbb50dfe322437249d9bcbc/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php#L209) to the source code of the `parse` method for reference.