# How can update Current Timezone in the main configuration?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, timezone, timezone-offset

**config/app.php**

```
'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
```

I'm trying to update my `app.timezone` base on clientTimeZone `Asia/Kolkata`

```
$date = new DateTime();
$timeZone = $date->getTimezone();
echo $timeZone->getName().PHP_EOL;

$timezone_offset_minutes = 330; 
$clientTimeZone = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $timezone_offset_minutes*60, false);
echo $clientTimeZone .PHP_EOL;

Session::put('clientTimeZone',$clientTimeZone);
config('app.timezone', $clientTimeZone);

$date = new DateTime();
$timeZone = $date->getTimezone();
echo $timeZone->getName() .PHP_EOL;
```

This is the result

```
America/New_York 
Asia/Kolkata 
America/New_York
```

I have a feeling that this

```
config('app.timezone', $clientTimeZone);
```

is not taking any effect

Comment: You have to use `Carbon` instances.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Carbon how to change timezone without changing the hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870577/laravel-carbon-how-to-change-timezone-without-changing-the-hour)

Comment: what is your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime class accept two args, the second one is `?DateTimeZone $timezone = null`. If it's omitted or null, the current timezone will be used.

```php
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$date = new DateTime('now', $timezone);
```

The Laravel's `app.timezone` config doesn't affect directly to DateTime.

On bootstrapping Laravel app it set up timezone this way

```
date_default_timezone_set($config->get('app.timezone', 'UTC'));
```

To work with client timezone you may set up it globally during session

```php
$timezone_offset_minutes = 330; 
$clientTimeZone = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $timezone_offset_minutes*60, false);
date_default_timezone_set($clientTimeZone);
```

Remember it doesn't affect any other apps, i.e. mysql. Mysql still will use `app.timezone` readed on application bootstrap.

I propose to pass client timezone to any methods, functions and use it this way

```php
$timezone_offset_minutes = 330; 
$clientTimeZone = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $timezone_offset_minutes*60, false);
$this->getClientDateTime(new DateTimeZone($clientTimeZone));

//...

public function getClientDateTime(DateTimeZone $dateTimeZone): string
{
    return new DateTime('now', $dateTimeZone->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```