# How can I overwrite timestamp to save into the database base on specific timezone?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, timezone

Right now my Laravel application save() any items into the database base on this timestamp. `America/New_York` because I configured it as `'timezone' => 'America/New_York',` in config/app.php.

**Goal**

I wish to overwrite timestamp based on other tz instead, ex.  `America/Chicago`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need too

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

So when you change the server to another timezone all timestamps will get the new time zone

setting the time zone goe like

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/Chicago';
```

Comment: I manually update my timezone in my mac to Texas time, I live in MA. I created an ajax from a front-end passed to the back-end, now I am in the back-end already know what my client timezone is (Asia/Kolkata) in my case, and I want my laravel to store a record base on this new time zone instead. Right now, it's 5:40 PM in Texas, and if I want new record use that time to store into the database even if my 'timezone' => 'America/New_York' in config/app.php. It will save as 6:40 PM.

Comment: Let me try this `SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Asia/Kolkata';` maybe that will force my app to store record in that timezone time instead.

Comment: I got an error : https://i.imgur.com/RjHZ8ij.png

I did this : https://i.imgur.com/GCm1c6j.png

Comment: an app sends the time you set for example 2022-01-01 00:00:00 and sends thisto to the server, which will save the utc time and a select will return the saved utc with the global time zone  as the quote already says

Comment: oh no this is a raw sql command, no püp or laravel

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do crazy stuff... What you have to do is:

- Store the time in a known timezone and never change that timezone again, it would be awesome if you use `UTC` as a default timezone.
- When you want to "convert" a timezone, you just `$model->created_at` (or anything that is a `Carbon` object) and do `$model->created_at->setTimezone('America/Chicago');` (for example).

The main idea is that when you already have a `Carbon` instance with a timestamp, you just change the timezone with `setTimezone` to the new one you want and it will return a new `Carbon` instance with that timezone...

Have a look at this [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870577/laravel-carbon-how-to-change-timezone-without-changing-the-hour).

Also, remember that `timestamp` is just an `integer` representing how many seconds have passed since `1970-01-01 00:00:01 (UTC)`, so if you say "give me a timestamp of a specific date and time on specific timezone" the `timestamp` will be always the same even if you change the timezone each time... that is the main idea of the `timestamp`...

If I say "What timestamp is for `1970-01-01 00:00:10`?", if you are on `UTC` you would get `10`, because 10 seconds passed since that specific `datetime`, if you are on UTC+1, it would still be `10` seconds, but you will display `1970-01-01 00:01:10`, because you are `1` hour ahead of `UTC`, if you are on `UTC-1` it will be `1969-12-31 23:00:10`, because you are `1` hour behind `UTC`, but you know how to do the conversion, that is why the value will be always the same disregarding the timezone, and that is also why it is `1970-01-01 00:00:00` and not any other specific `datetime`, because if you do not know which is the specific `datetime` you would not know how to do the conversion.

It is very important that you understand what you are working with, so to help you understand better, have a look at [this blog](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx) explaining the same thing but in more detail.

Answer (score -1):

The timestamp generated in PHP is in UTC time regardless of your local timezone setting.

You can adjust the timezone of the timestamp before it is displayed in the UI using [setTimezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php).

Reference:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php
- 

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Comment: I don’t think think that what I’m looking for. I’m using Laravel and it was set in the config file

Comment: No, the setTimezone function adjusts the display timezone of a particular datetime object. It is not a global setting like your Laravel configuration. Take a look at the setTimezone documentation in the answer and you will see that it does literally exactly what you are asking for.